# Store array in database

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I want to store my multiple select options into database. Here's my select option:

```
<select name="service_skillsreq[]" class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
<option value=""> </option> 
</select>
```

And here's my model.

```
$data               = new self;
$data->spec_id      = self::where('id', Auth::user()->id);
$data->skills_name  = $request['service_skillsreq'];
$data->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing in my project, but I followed a different method using controller.I hope this may help you to solve your problem.
In your controller `store()` method

```
$service = Input::get('service_skillsreq');       //html form name field without []

    $data = []; //making an array

    foreach($service as $srv) {         //for every input you have array generate
        $data[] = [
            'skills_name' => $srv,   

        ]; 
    }

        Model_name::insert($data);     //laravel insert it to the database without error`
```

Comment: In this method, your model should only have table name, and its fields you are going to fill. `skills_name` is a column name in your table.

Comment: Was this the solution for your problem? If so please accept it as the answer.